# Antlr : mutually left-recursive rule

Tags: antlr

i have this rule in antlr :

```
anREs : anRE 
      | ('(' anREs ')') =>  '(' anREs ')'
      | (anREs '|' anREs) =>  anREs '|' anREs   ;
```

where the anRE is a regular expression , when i want to compile the rules file i have this error message due to 3rd alternative in last rule :

> error(210):  The following sets of
>   rules are mutually left-recursive
>   [anREs]

how i can re write this rule ?

thanks

Comment: @ Bart Kiers thanks for your help , you are right i can solve this problem by delete this alternative but i need it , and i cant use PCRE because i need to implement special features in my rules .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your left recursion:

```
  ... | (anREs '|' anREs) =>  anREs '|' anREs   ;
```

Worse, its ambiguous.  If you have  anREs_1 | anREs_2 | anREs3  as input,
it isn't clear what the subterms of the | operator are.

I'd expect this to solve the problem, and resolve the ambiguity, too:

```
  ... | (anRE '|' anREs) =>  anRE '|' anREs   ;
```

Comment: Why not? You have  '(' anREs ')' and anREs derives to anRE.  Did you actually try it?